# Get request body from custom lambda authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a HTTP API gateway with a custom lambda authorizer. I need to get the request body to determine whether or not to authorize the request but currently I am only getting the request headers. Is there any way I can do this?

Amazon Q said that the lambda authorizer will receive the entire request object as a parameter however this has not been the case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Q was probably hallucinating. What does the actual documentation say? Did you create a token-based authorizer or a [request-based](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) authorizer?

Looking at [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-input.html), it appears that the request body will **not** be passed to the authorizer function. Only these values will be passed to a request-based authorizer:

> headers, path parameters, query string parameters, stage variables, and some of request context variables